# Overlay two pcolormesh plots with MemoryError

Tags: python, matplotlib, out-of-memory

I am trying to visualize two raster maps with pcolormesh. The both matrices have an array size of (2914, 3560).

```py
def create_contour(x,y,z_conversion,z_disadvantage, title, unit):
    graphWidth = 800 # units are pixels
    graphHeight = 600 # units are pixels    
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)
    axes.set_title(title) # add a title for contour plot
    vmin_set = max(np.nanmin(z_conversion), np.nanmin(z_disadvantage))
    vmax_set = min(np.nanmax(z_conversion), np.nanmax(z_disadvantage))

    plt.pcolormesh(x, y, z_conversion,
                   vmin=vmin_set,
                   vmax=vmax_set,
                    cmap = "Blues", shading='nearest', label='conversion')
    plt.pcolormesh(x, y, np.ma.masked_where(np.isnan(z_disadvantage),z_disadvantage),
                   vmin=vmin_set,
                   vmax=vmax_set,
                    cmap = "Blues", shading='nearest', label='disadvantage',hatch='/')
    
    cbar = plt.colorbar()
    cbar.set_label(unit)
    plt.show()
```

When I plotted either 'z_conversion' or 'z_disadvantage', everything is fine. However, when I plotted these two matrixes in the same figure together. I got this map and this error.

[image]

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 317. MiB for an array with shape (10373840, 4) and data type float64

It seems that the array size 10373840 is the product of the individual matrix.

I am really grateful if you have any idea about how to solve the problem.